# Lifting a function

Tags: function, functional-programming, f#, lifting

As a F# newbie, I am having problems with understanding the term "Lifting" and I can not properly lift a function.

For example how can I lift the below function and how it will effect the functions behavior.

```
let add item element = item :: element
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Check out this page http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/ it has the best explanations with graphical representations of the idea of lifting.

The site is a treasure trove of good material for understanding F# in particular and functional programming in general.

In simple terms, the idea of lifting refers to taking a function `f` that works with a simple type and creating a new version `liftedF` that works with a generic type. How do we do this? We take the function `f` pass it to another function and it returns a "new and improved" version of `f`. For instance say you have a simple function that returns the square of an integer:

```
let square x = x * x    // val square : int -> int
```

Simple right? You pass an `int` and it returns another `int`.

Now lets create a new version like this:

```
let squareArray xA = Array.map square xA  // val squareArray : int [] -> int []
```

Wow! `squareArray` can square a whole array of integers and it was so easy to create! All I needed to do is pass `square` to `Array.map`.

Look at the signatures `square` is `int -> int` and `squareArray` is `int [] -> int []`. That is lifting!

If you look at the signature of `Array.map` is `('a -> 'b) -> 'a [] -> 'b []`
which can be interpreted as receiving a function from type `'a` to `'b` and an array of `'a`s and returning an array of `'b`s. But it can also be interpreted as receiving a function from `'a` to `'b`'and returning a lifted function from `'a[]` to `'b[]`:

- `('a -> 'b) ->  'a [] -> 'b []`  is the same as
- `('a -> 'b) -> ('a [] -> 'b [])`

You can lift functions to any generic types.
What is a generic type? It is a type that has another type as a parameter, there are many generic types that you probably already know:

- `List<'t>` (also expressed as `'t list`) is generic because you can have lists of different types like `List<int>`, `List<string>`, `List<int * string>`, `...`
- `Array<'t>` : `Array<int>`, `Array<string>`, `Array<int * string>`, `...`
- `Option<'t>` : `Option<int>`, `Option<string>`, `Option<int * string>`, `...`
- `Result<'t,'r>` : `Result<int, string>`, `Result<string, string>`, `...`

You can lift functions to other generic types:

```
let squareOption xO = Option.map square xO  // val squareOption : int option -> int option
let stringArray  sL = Array.map  string sL  // val stringArray : int [] -> string []
```

It is all in the function signatures. We can take a function from...

- `int -> int` and get a `List<int> -> List<int>` function
- ... or from `int -> int`  to `Option<int> -> Option<int>`
- ... or from `string -> float` to `string [] -> float[]`

Comment: Excellent explanation - pity the question was closed because it's something that confuses a lot of newbies...